# Problem booting with NVidia graphics

Tags: system-installation, boot

Today I tried to install elementary OS on my PC alongside Windows 10 but I've got error when I tried to launch bootable usb (see photo). How can I install it?
I want to try Linux for my first time.

My PC specs:

- Processor: AMD A8-7650K 3.8GHz
- RAM: HyperX FURY DDR3-1866 2x4GB
- Motherboard: MSI A88XM-E35 V2
- Graphics card: Asus GeForce GTX 950 STRIX 2GB

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Go into the BIOS menu and make sure internal graphics are disabled. If that doesn't work, try hitting the 'e' key in the grub boot menu, and adding 'nomodeset=1' to the end of the line that starts with 'linux'. Then hit F10 to continue booting.